# SQL 'Check Availability' statement

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have two database tables, one storing properties, and the other storing bookings for the properties. Here is a simplified version of the table structures:

```
property
+-------------------+--------------+
| Field             | Type         |
+-------------------+--------------+
| id                | int(11)      |
| status            | int(1)       |
| title             | varchar(150) |
+-------------------+--------------+

booking
+-------------------+--------------+
| Field             | Type         |
+-------------------+--------------+
| id                | int(11)      |
| status            | int(1)       |
| property_id       | int(11)      |
| start_date        | date         |
| end_date          | date         |
+-------------------+--------------+
```

I have a search form with a start and end date to see what properties are available during a given period. Eg "What properties are available for rental between 2012-12-01 and 2012-12-07".

I have the following SQL which works to a degree:

```
SELECT p.id, p.title FROM property p WHERE p.status=1 AND p.id NOT IN (SELECT 
b.property_id FROM booking b WHERE (b.status=1 OR b.status=2 OR b.status=3 OR 
b.status=6) AND NOT (b.enddate < '2013-05-30' OR b.startdate > '2013-05-24')) 
ORDER BY p.title ASC
```

The problem is, it doesn't handle overlapping of dates. If the search is for a date range within an existing booking, the SQL works fine and the property isn't returned. However, if the search dates overlap the booking dates,properties still get returned, even though they are booked for part of the search period.

I've setup an SQL fiddle here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d02e1/4 - there are 5 queries - the first 2 work ok. The properties I need returned are as follows:

- Query 1 (working) - 1, 2 and 3
- Query 2 (working) - 2 and 3
- Query 3 (not working) - 2 and 3
- Query 4 (not working) - 2 and 3
- Query 5 (not working) - 2 and 3

Any help or advice is much appreciated.

UPDATE;

I think my wording might be a little unclear. What I'm trying to do is get a list of properties that are available for rental for a given date range (the search dates). A property would be unavailable if; the search dates are within an existing booking date range, or overlap it at either end. If there are no bookings covering any period between the search dates, then the property is available.

Answer (score 0):

Need something like this?:

```
SELECT p.id, p.title 
FROM property p 
WHERE p.status=1 AND p.id NOT IN (
SELECT b.property_id 
    FROM booking b 
    WHERE (b.status IN (1, 2, 3, 6)) 
        AND (b.end_date BETWEEN '2012-12-01' AND '2012-12-30'
        OR b.start_date BETWEEN '2012-12-01' AND '2012-12-30')
) 
ORDER BY p.title ASC;
```

It returns 2 and 3

Comment: That's almost got it, but now if you search with dates within an existing booking date range, that property appears when it shouldn't (ie property 1 shouldn't appear for any of the queries in this example: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d02e1/45)

Comment: I think my wording probably was a little unclear. What I'm trying to do is get a list of properties that are available for rental for a given date range (the search dates). A property would be unavailable if; the search dates are within an existing booking date range, or overlap it at either end. If there are no bookings covering any period between the search dates, then the property is available.

Answer (score 0):

Managed to solve it here is the fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d02e1/64